# Open top-left menu in Dolphin explorer with keyboard shortcut

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts, plasma, dolphin, kde-neon

I am looking for a way to open this menu in the Dolphin file explorer with a keyboard shortcut. (It can be invoked by clicking on the icon in the top-left.)

[image]

I looked through the available keyboard shortcuts, but I couldn't find anything that looked like it referenced this menu.

For reference, I am trying to emulate the behavior on Windows where a similar menu appears in response to the `Alt-Space` shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found the relevant shortcut. It is (in retrospect, obviously) not a Dolphin setting but a KWin setting, found under System Settings > Shortcuts > KWin > Window Operations Menu. The default shortcut is `Alt+F3`, but `Alt+Space` can be assigned.

If it doesn't work, try deselecting it from KRunner in the same settings area.